# Display entityreference field in search-result.tpl

Tags: entities, search

The entityreference field (field_parent) shows up in node.tpl using `print render($content);`, but isn't displayed in search-result.tpl. My search-result.tpl looks like this right now:

```
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>

  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>

  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>


    <div class="submitted">
    <div class="imported-text">Imported on <?php print $info_split['date']; ?>.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hr"></div>

    <div class="content">
    <div class="comments-link"><a href="<?php print $url; ?>">Comments</a></div>
    <div class="other-content">

    <div class="field-name-field-download"><a href="<?php print $result['node']-> field_download[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url'] ?>">Download</a></div>
    <div class="field-name-field-lipsum"><span class="lipsum">Lipsum:</span> <?php print $result['node']-> field_lipsum[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ?></div>


    </div>
    </div>

</li>
```

I tried using `<?php print $result['node']-> field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] ?>` but it gives me the error "Notice: Undefined index: value in include() (line 25 of ...\search-result.tpl.php)."

`<?php print $result['node']-> field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entity'] ?>` gives

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in include() (line 25 of ...\search-result.tpl.php).

`<?php print $result['node']-> field_parent[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['entityreference'] ?>`

Notice: Undefined index: entityreference in include() (line 25 of ...\search-result.tpl.php).

Comment: have you tried using dpm($result) from the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module? it would give you the array structure to more easily find the correct elements

Comment: I've never used devel. Both documentation links I tried were dead, how can I use dpm($result) to solve this?

Comment: Just enable the devel module @Geoff linked to and then add `<?php dpm($result); ?>` to the top of `search-result.tpl.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using teaser view as my search result. My search-result.tpl file now looks like:

```
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

<?php $v = node_view($result['node'], 'teaser'); print render($v); ?>

</li>
```